# Getting cron job to work with wp-cron.php for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am trying to enable digests to be sent by the Buddypress group email notification plugin for Buddypress/Wordpress, without success.

Here's what's happened so far:

1. I have confirmed that all items are getting added to the digest list generated by the plugin by visiting the page that shows these, i.e. http://[site url]/?sum=1
2. I am able to manually trigger the sending of digests by visiting the URL for wp-cron.php, i.e. http://[site url]/wp-cron.php in my browser.

So, the issue is with the triggering of wp-cron.php. Having researched this it seems like it would be a good idea for me to set up a cron job on my server, as there is not much traffic to my site and the built in WordPress pseudo cron job only gets triggered when someone visits the site.

The issue I now have is what to enter for the command for the cron job. I have tried many things, but I currently have this:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/wp-cron.php
```

I have it set up to email me when each cron job runs, and this is what the above command returned:

```
--2012-07-03 18:15:01-- http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/wp-cron.php
Resolving soteriabrighton.co.uk... 208.53.158.38
Connecting to soteriabrighton.co.uk|208.53.158.38|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 0 [text/html]
Saving to: `/dev/null'

0K 0.00 =0s

2012-07-03 18:15:04 (0.00 B/s) - `/dev/null' saved [0/0]
```

To my untrained eye it looks like it worked OK, and yet no digests were sent out.

Any help to get this fixed/with troubleshooting steps would be much appreciated.

Comment: Very hosting company specific... checked in their faq on the correct mechanism for for calling pages or executing php directly?

Comment: I'm with Cirtex and tried to get them to set up a cron job. They could barely construct a sentence in English, let alone write the correct command for a cron job!  Everything they tried failed. The command above is from an article I found online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried to google for it or check thei9r forums - 2 seconds gave me:

http://forums.cirtexhosting.com/website-development-scripting/1395-cron-job.html

> wget sometimes is permissioned to be not allowed by user so some
>   servers its disabled for users. Might want to try curl, lynx, if those
>   are disabled too, you can try just /usr/bin/local/php
>   /home/youruser/public_html/file.php for example will do or php -q -f
>   /home/user/public_html/file.php

also seems direct php works, i.e:

```
php -q -f /home/user/public_html/file.php
```

Alother pages suggests (for critex):

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php5 -q /full-path/yours-php5-script.php5
```

Comment: Thanks.  The one that seems to be working from those you included above is `php -q -f /home/user/public_html/file.php`.  I say seems to be working because I haven't been able to get it to work consistently, but that may be something to do with the way the Buddypress Group Email Notification plugin is queueing the digest items.  What certainly isn't happening is that I am not getting an email confirming that the cron job has run with the above command.  Do you know why this would be?

Comment: I use it myself to be honest and never had any problems with wp-cron :| Not sure about the email confirming cron has ran - not sure I have had that either.

Comment: OK, thanks Brian.  I'll leave it as it is and check that the digest gets sent out tomorrow, and will report back.

Comment: to satisfy you're own curiosity, you could make a really simple test to do a mail and add it as it's own cron - to verify the mailing side of things?

Comment: Thanks. Being new to cron jobs I'm not sure how I would go about this. Any pointers or links to articles welcome!

Comment: Unfortunately even though the cron job worked fine on the first day, it hasn't on subsequent days, suggesting that the issue is not with the command, but with a fault on the server.  I have contacted my host to let them know.  I will report back.

Comment: There was a fault with the server.  All seems to working well now.  with `php -q -f /home/user/public_html/file.php`